# Bootstrap 5.3 generate alternative color classes using Sass

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5, color-scheme

I use a Bootstrap 5.3 theme. I'd like a user to be able to override that the "primary" color theme should be. So instead of blue, maybe a purple or orange.

My plan is to generate "orange-as-primary.css", "purple-as-primary.css", etc, and include those after the standard "bootstrap.css" to override the classes dynamically (say a dropdown menu in the frontend).

The [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color/) shows how to generate custom text color classes (e.g., `.text-purple-500`) using Sass:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";
@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";

$all-colors: map-merge-multiple($blues, $indigos, $purples, $pinks, $reds, $oranges, $yellows, $greens, $teals, $cyans);

$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "color": map-merge(
      map-get($utilities, "color"),
      (
        values: map-merge(
          map-get(map-get($utilities, "color"), "values"),
          (
            $all-colors
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
);

@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

I'm not Sass-savvy enough to adapt it to my use case and generate all derived css rules (for borders, hover, active colors etc) for all components (`text-primary`, `alert-primary`, `btn-primary`, etc).

Any suggestions or alternative approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Seems an old question with no answer. But Bootstrap 5.3 is quite uptodate so this question is maybe still relevant. Since Bootstrap is quite old now already and very blown it can become very heavy to overlook all parts and find the right answer to a problem. Bootstrap never intended to be best for fine-tuning and is known for its great look out-of-the box.

> Any suggestions or alternative approaches?

What you can do is to use some of the Bootstrap color theme generators out there in the web to create your own Bootstrap color scheme. Or, to answer to "alternative approaches": you can use alternative tools, like the color generator of [JASS](https://github.com/diqidoq/jass), which would integrate well with Bootstrap since it uses color hex code classes instead of .primary, etc. So they do not get in the way to each other.